# Select tables based on containing text in preceding h3 elements

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

```
  <h3>
    <strong>Tier 1 - 1 USD | 1 EUR</strong>
  </h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Game
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Ratings
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Cards
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Cheevos
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Details
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Platforms
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Bundled
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Retail Price
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/280160/" title="Action, Adventure, Indie, Strategy, Singleplayer, Story Rich, Atmospheric, Multiplayer, Great Soundtrack, Co-op, Open World, Gore, Third Person, Online Co-Op" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">Aragami</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">90% of 7112
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-280160" title="9 cards" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">❤</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=280160" title="51 achievements" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?app=280160">3.00 CV</a>     app/280160
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">W M L
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/aragami,&amp;bundle" title="1 bundle + 1 special ■ Humble Staff Picks Bundle: Scribble! (3 years ago, tier 2) ■ Platinum Collection - Build Your Own Bundle (Feb / Mar 2021) (5 months ago)" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">1</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/aragami/info" title="19.99€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$19.99</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h3>
    <strong>Tier 2 - BTA (initial: $6)</strong>
  </h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Game
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Ratings
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Cards
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Cheevos
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Details
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Platforms
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Bundled
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Retail Price
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/551770/" title="Action, Adventure, Indie, Puzzle, Sci-fi, Singleplayer, Story Rich, Atmospheric, Great Soundtrack, Horror, Third Person, Cyberpunk, Stealth, Female Protagonist" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">ECHO</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">80% of 1198
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">-
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=551770" title="47 achievements" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?app=551770">3.75 CV</a>     app/551770
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">W
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/echo,&amp;bundle" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">0</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/echo/info" title="22.99€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$24.99</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/268130/" title="Action, Adventure, Indie, Strategy, Sci-fi, Singleplayer, Space, Top-Down, Open World, Rogue-like, Tactical, 2D, Rogue-lite, Top-Down Shooter" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">Heat Signature</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">94% of 5571
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-268130" title="8 cards" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">❤</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=268130" title="70 achievements" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?app=268130">2.25 CV</a>     app/268130
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">W
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/heatsignature,&amp;bundle" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">0</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/heatsignature/info" title="12.99€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$14.99</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/355790/" title="Action, Adventure, RPG, Singleplayer, Comedy, Atmospheric, Multiplayer, Co-op, Open World, Violent, Third Person, Difficult, Fantasy, Dark Fantasy" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">Styx: Shards of Darkness</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">83% of 2431
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-355790" title="7 cards" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">❤</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=355790" title="38 achievements" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?app=355790">3.00 CV</a>     app/355790
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">W
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/styxshardsofdarkness,&amp;bundle" title="2 bundles + 3 specials ■ Kingslayer Bundle (2 years ago) ■ June 2018 Humble Monthly #32 (3 years ago) ■ Platinum Collection - Build Your Own Bundle (Mar 2020) (16 months ago) ⏸ Festival Mystery Bundle (2 years ago) ⏸ Deluxe Mystery Game (2 years ago)" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">2</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/styxshardsofdarkness/info" title="19.99€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$19.99</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h3>
    <strong>Tier 3 - 12 USD</strong>
  </h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Game
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Ratings
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Cards
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Cheevos
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Details
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Platforms
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Bundled
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Retail Price
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/sub/272966/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Gold Edition</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">(Included game has cards)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">-
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?q=HITMAN+2+-+Gold+Edition">15.00 CV</a>     sub/272966
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/hitmaniigoldedition,&amp;bundle" title="0 bundles + 8 specials ⏸ Spring Mystery Bundle (16 months ago) ⏸ Platinum Mystery Bundle (22 months ago) ⏸ Mystery Madness Bundle (22 months ago) ⏸ Staff Picks - Buy More, Save More (2 years ago) ⏸ Elite Mystery Bundle (2 years ago) ⏸ Elite Mystery Bundle (2 years ago) ⏸ Festival Mystery Bundle (2 years ago) ⏸ Deluxe Mystery Game (2 years ago)" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">0*</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/hitmaniigoldedition/info" title="89.99€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$99.99</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://steamdb.info/sub/216806/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN: Game of the Year Edition</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">Corresponds to 
          <a href="https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/4854/" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">this</a> store bundle
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">(Included game has cards)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">-
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?q=HITMAN%3A+Game+of+the+Year+Edition">11.09 CV</a>     sub/216806
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/hitmangameofyearedition,&amp;bundle" title="⏸ Free Game Giveaway 2019-Nov-1 (22 months ago)" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">0*</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/hitmangameofyearedition/info" title="71.91€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$73.91</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/417290/" title="Action, Adventure, Indie, RPG, Singleplayer, Action RPG, Story Rich, Atmospheric, Great Soundtrack, Horror, Open World, Exploration, Medieval, Third Person" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">Ghost of a Tale</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">92% of 3029
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">-
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=417290" title="20 achievements" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://www.steamgifts.com/giveaways/search?app=417290">3.75 CV</a>     app/417290
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">W
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/specials/#/filter:search/ghostofatale,&amp;bundle" title="0 bundles + 2 specials ⏸ Deluxe Mystery Game (2 years ago) ⏸ Winter Mystery Bundle (2 years ago)" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">0*</a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
          <a href="https://isthereanydeal.com/game/ghostofatale/info" title="22.99€" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">$24.99</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <ul>
    <li>10% Humble store coupon for Hitman 3
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>
    <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/sub/272966/" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Gold Edition</a></strong> is delivered as one key that activates the following apps:
  </h3>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left;">Game
        </th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Ratings
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/863550/" title="Action, Strategy, Puzzle, Singleplayer, Atmospheric, Shooter, Multiplayer, Great Soundtrack, Co-op, Open World, Sandbox, Gore, Violent, Third Person" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™ 2</a></strong>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">91% of 24178
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950556/" title="Action, Gore, Violent, Stealth" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™&nbsp;2 - Hawke's&nbsp;Bay</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">92% of 28
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950557/" title="Action, Gore, Violent, Stealth" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™&nbsp;2 - Miami</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">84% of 52
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950558/" title="Action, Gore, Violent" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Santa Fortuna</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">96% of 27
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950559/" title="Action, Gore, Violent" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN&nbsp;2 - Mumbai</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">77% of 27
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950560/" title="Action, Gore, Violent" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™&nbsp;2 - Whittleton Creek</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">94% of 34
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950561/" title="Action, Gore, Violent" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™&nbsp;2 - Isle of Sgàil</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">86% of 23
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/950562/" title="Action, Gore, Violent" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™&nbsp;2 - Himmelstein</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">75% of 28
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957690/" title="Action, Gore, Violent, Stealth, Assassin" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN&nbsp;2 - Expansion Pass</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">68% of 388
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957691/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Expansion Pack 1</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957692/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Expansion Pack 2</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957693/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Winter Sports Pack</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957694/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Smart Casual Pack</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957695/" title="Action" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™ 2 - Special Assignments Pack 1</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">100% of 1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957696/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Expansion Mission Pack 2</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957697/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Executive Pack</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957698/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Collector's Pack</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957730/" title="Action" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - New York</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">100% of 1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957731/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Expansion Map 2</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957733/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN&nbsp;2 - Hantu Port</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/957735/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN 2 - Siberia</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/972340/" title="" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™ 2 - Gold Edition</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">No user reviews
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">
          <strong><a href="https://store.steampowered.com/app/977941/" title="Action, Strategy, Puzzle, Singleplayer, Atmospheric, Shooter, Multiplayer, Great Soundtrack, Co-op, Open World, Sandbox, Gore, Violent, Third Person" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">HITMAN™ 2 - Early Access</a></strong> (DLC)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">91% of 24087
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Right, so here are four tables. What I'm trying to achieve is selecting only tables where their preceding element is h3 and where that h3 contains 'Tier' or 'Games'.

I can't really wrap my head around this at all. I've come up with 2 options (one that I've been religiously repeating like I'm gonna force it to give me the needed result or something).
The first one is:

```
//h3[contains (., 'Tier') or (., 'Games')]/following::table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

This one seems very straightforward to me, yet it doesn't get the needed result.
The other one is:

```
//table[preceding-sibling::h3[contains(., 'Tier') or (., 'Games')]]/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

This one makes even more sense, yet again it doesn't get the needed results.

Comment: The answer that you've accepted, He has not used `or` operator in his xpath which is a crucial thing for this particular ticket. from where did you get the reference of or operator in xpath ? @Pavle Ćurčić. You are almost using my solution without any credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's little tricky but found the solution. If you see below, all the `table` and `h3` tags are siblings. In your `xPath` you are using `table/tbody/tr/td[1]` but not specifying which table you are referring.

[image]

I used the table index to get elements of particular table. Like `following-sibling::table[1]`

**xPath for Tier1 table**: Returns only `td` tags of `Tier1` table.

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Tier 1 - 1 USD')]//parent::h3//following-sibling::table[1]//tbody//tr//td
```

**xPath for Tier2 table**: Returns only `td` tags of `Tier2` table.

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Tier 2 - BTA')]//parent::h3//following-sibling::table[1]//tbody//tr//td
```

**xPath for Tier3 table**: Returns only `td` tags of `Tier3` table.

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Tier 3 - 12 USD')]//parent::h3//following-sibling::table[1]//tbody//tr//td
```

**Dynamic xPath for all tables:**

```
//strong[contains(text(),' + tableName + ')]//parent::h3//following-sibling::table[1]//tbody//tr//td
```

Comment: I really liked the index on the table element. What I ended up using is:
//h3[contains(., 'Tier') or contains(., 'Games')]/following-sibling::table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]
Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are **4** `h3 tags` that you've shared.

`3` of them contains Tier (not directly but their child contains those text). so you could use the below xapth :

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Tier') or contains(text(), 'Games')]/parent::h3
```

I see that you are interested in `tr/td[1]` **element**, if so, please use

```
//strong[contains(text(),'Tier') or contains(text(), 'Games')]/parent::h3/following-sibling::table/descendant::tr/td[1]
```